# Owl carousel with lightbox

Tags: carousel, lightbox, owl-carousel-2

I am trying to add a lightbox into in owl carousel already I tried few of methods but was impossible is somebody that sort it out? Anything that I am doing in my themes owl carousel is impossible to add the lightbox feature. Please if you have any idea help me..

** I want to add it in the users gallery that is by default owl carousel I tried Venobox I show that some people achieve great results but for this didn't help at all

Thanks in Advance